# RavenDB 4.0 - BulkInsertOptions?

Tags: c#, ravendb, ravendb4

As a part of migration `RavenDB 3.0` to `RavenDB 4.0` I came across that new version has missing `BulkInsertOptions` type, has that been moved somewhere, or completely removed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The bulk insert options are not meaningful in 4.0, so were removed.
What options are you trying to set?

Comment: `new BulkInsertOptions { OverwriteExisting = true, SkipOverwriteIfUnchanged = true, BatchSize = 128, WriteTimeoutMilliseconds = 30000}`

Comment: You can ignore all of these, then.

Comment: And what about `new BulkInsertOptions { OverwriteExisting = false }`

Comment: That isn't supported